# Accessing session Variable

Tags: python, django, variables, templates, session

I have successfully built a custom user registration system as one module and I have one other module named article. I want to display the user logged in from my custom user registeration module in the templates of article module. 
I'm using {{if user.is_authenticated}} display {{user}} to display the username in my templates.

I am able to access it in custom user registration templates but not in the articles templates. I want to display the username on the navbar which is same for both the apps.

what should i do so that the username is accessible in the entire project, not just in the template rendered.

I'm using django 1.8 and i have also tried creating a session variable in my views.py file but it also works in the same app.

views.py of the project

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import auth
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from custom_user.forms import CustomUserCreationForm
from django.utils import timezone

def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('login.html', c)

def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        request.session['user_id'] = user.id
        request.session['user_email'] = user.email
        return render(request, "loggedin.html", {},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/invalid')

def loggedin(request):
    return render_to_response('loggedin.html', {})

def invalid_login(request):
    return render_to_response('invalid_login.html')
```

template base.py

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="/subscribe/">Subscribe</a></li>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href="/">{{user}}</a></li>
                <li><a href="/accounts/logout/">Logout</a></li>
                {% else %}
                <li><a href="/accounts/login/">Login</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
```

views.py of article app

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.conf import settings
from article.models import Article, Comment, Subscribers
from forms import ArticleForm, CommentForm, SubscriptionForm, ActivateSubscriberForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from random import randrange
from signup.views import *
# from .forms import RegistrationForm

# Create your views here.

def articles(request):
    return render_to_response('articles.html',
        {'articles':Article.objects.all().order_by('-id'),'last':Article.objects.earliest('-pub_date')})

def article(request, article_id=1):
    return render_to_response('article.html',
        {'article':Article.objects.get(id=article_id)})
```

When user is authenticated then loggedin.html is rendered and there i have created a link to go to articles app which uses the same base.py template.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to access authentication data if you've got the `'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'` processor in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.

However, it is present by default - perhaps you've removed it?

Finally, the documentation is very helpful on that subject: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates

Comment: As @Daniel Roseman said, you are missing the context - either move to `render` or add the context. And mark his answer as the right one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually shown any code, but the problem is almost certainly how you are rendering the template. As Marcanpilami points out, the `user` variable is automatically added by the template context processors; but context processors are only run if you use a RequestContext to render your template. That means, these days, ensuring that you use the `render` shortcut, rather than `render_to_response`.

(For completeness sake, you *can* use `render_to_response` as long as you pass it `context_instance=RequestContext`, but it's almost always easier to just use `render`).

Comment: Well, precisely as I said, you're using `render_to_response` instead of `render`.